# Get pagseguro session id

Tags: laravel-8

I'm trying to get the pagseguro session id, but when I send a request via post, I get the status 200, but I get null, when I make the request via form I can get the id but by ajax it returns null to use laravel 8

```
//Route
Route::post('getsession', [\App\Http\Controllers\Pagseguro\PagseguroController::class, 'getSession'])->name('getsession');

//Controller
class PagseguroController extends Controller
{
     public function getSession()
     {
         $response = Http::post('https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/sessions?email=$email&token=$token');    

         dd($response->json());
     }
}

//View
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
 </head>
<body class="font-sans antialiased">

<a href="" class="btn btn-primary" id="sign">GET ID SESSION</a>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    //disparar no momento da compra - sign-plan
    $('#sign').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
            url: "{{ url('getsession') }}",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    }); 
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not call `/sessions` directly in the frontend, as this would expose your e-mail and token. You **must** do this call in the backend side of your application. (It seems you already did that this way.)

With the result  you may invoke `PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId('SESSION_ID');`.

This is explained [here](https://dev.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v1/reference/transparente-biblioteca-javascript) in details and with examples.

And answering your question, it's most likely that Sandbox was out of service when you submitted the form. Specially if you did the test during the night. That's why you probably got a null result.

⚠️ PagSeguro Sandbox environment is not reliable and you may face this kind of issues, specially when obtaining the sessionId, credit card tokens and/or installments.